# pandas.DataFrame: difference between inplace = True and assigning the same variable?

Tags: python, pandas, function, variable-assignment, in-place

I am replacing `-np.inf` and `np.inf` with `np.nan` within a pandas data frame.

However, using the inplace = True, I get a warning:

```
df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan, inplace = True)

SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

whereas just re-assigning the variable to itself (not sure whether this is a smart idea), but that seems to "solve" the issue:

```
df = df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)
```

I have read in another question that python distinguish between a copy and a view, and if it's not clear somehow modifying one variable could affect the other too.

Should restrain from making use of `inplace`?

Just as background: I have a data frame with stock prices, however with missing value. I have a function that uses this data frame, but "cleans" up the data before processing.

```
def func(df):
   df_aux = df.dropna(axis = 1)
   df_aux.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan, inplace = True)
   df_aux.fillna(method = 'ffill', inplace = True)

   some calculation with df_aux

   return x
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`copy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html):

```
df_aux = df.dropna(axis = 1).copy()
```

If you modify values in `df_aux` later you will find that the modifications do not propagate back to the original data `df`, and that Pandas does warning.

Answer (score 0):

jezrael's answer is only silencing the warning with the assumption that you want to copy.

Using `inplace` is valid if you want to modify rather than copy but you need to use it consistently to avoid warnings:

```
def func(df):
   df.dropna(axis = 1, inplace=True)
   df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan, inplace=True)
   df.fillna(method = 'ffill', inplace=True)

   # some calculation with df

   return x
```